# How to get row and column fby using Cells.Find

Tags: excel, row, cells, vba

i'm using this code trying to get row and column where there is the cell which i'm looking for but it returns nothing. Can anyone help me with this.

```
i = 1

    Do While Workbooks("Lisses.xls").Sheets("Components").Cells(i, 2).Value <> ""
        Set cell = Cells.Find(What:=Workbooks("Lisses.xls").Sheets("Components").Cells(i, 2).Value)
        Dim a() As String
        a = Split(cell.Address, "$")

        Workbooks("macro_example.xlsx").Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(i, 7).Value = Workbooks("COMPSTK.xls").Sheets("COMPSTK").Cells(a(1), a(2)).Value
        i = i + 1                                                'Passe à la ligne suivante
    Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a string array - that's just overcomplicating it.

The `cell` variable is a Range object, which has `.Row` and `.Column` properties. You can use these rather than `a(1)` and `a(2)`, i.e. `Sheets("COMPSTK").Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column).Value`

Alternatively you could use the `.Address` property of `cell`, i.e. `Sheets("COMPSTK").Range(cell.Address).Value`. I haven't checked if this works or not, but it's worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

I Found it,
i Just used ActiveCell to select the cell i'm looking for

```
Do While Workbooks("Lisses.xls").Sheets("Components").Cells(i, 2).Value <> ""
        Set o = Cells.Find(What:=Workbooks("Lisses.xls").Sheets("Components").Cells(i, 2).Value)
        If Not o Is Nothing Then
        o.Activate
        Workbooks("Lisses.xls").Sheets("Components").Cells(i, 2).Value = Workbooks("COMPSTK.xls").Sheets("COMPSTK").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 7).Value
        End If

        i = i + 1                                                'Passe à la ligne suivante
    Loop
```